# Pattern prefix-function computation in Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, knuth-morris-pratt

Is there any possibility in the prefix-function of a given pattern to have something like this,

0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 `4 5 3 4 5` 6 7 0 1 2

In the above prefix function after 4 5 is there only possibility of either 6 or 0? If there is a possibility  for e.g 3(less than 5 and greater than 0) after 4 5 as in the above one then how the pattern should be.

I can think of patterns only similar to this one,

```
a b a b a b a b c a 
0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you insist on having an example with 5? I can show you an example pattern that has 3 after 6.

Comment: I saw your answer, it is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example pattern where you have fail link 4 after 6:

```
a b c a b c d a b c a b c a
0 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 4
```

Comment: I am using fail links as defined in the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: @AnanthaKrishnan 6 and 7 in your fail links are for sure wrong. The rest is just a matter of interpretation...

Comment: @AnanthaKrishnan izomorphius already did it. The only thing that is a matter of interpretation is whether you place one additional 0 like he did or not (like you). Both ways work you just code the usage of the failure links a bit differently

Comment: Why do you have 1 for "abcab" sequence?  Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: @AlexeyAlexandrov in fact I believe there are more than 1 mistakes above. I really don't remember what I was thinking back then. I will fix the fail links. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your particular example is impossible. When you start constructing a string from the desired prefix table, you get

```
0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2
a b a b a c a b a b a
```

1. first symbol arbitrary, say a
2. second symbol must be different from first, or the prefix length would be 1
3. third must be the same as first
4. fourth must be the same as second
5. fifth must be the same as third
6. can be neither of the two symbols used so far, a would give a prefix length of 1, b of 4
7. seventh must be first
8. must be second
9. must be third
10. must be fourth
11. must be fifth
12. a would give a prefix length of 1, b would give 4, c would give 6, everything else gives 0

The entry in the table corresponding to the prefix of length `p` gives the width of the widest border `b` of that prefix, say `w`. The next entry can only be `w+1` (if `b` is extensible), 0 (if no prefix matches), or one more than the width of some border of `b`.

So if `table[p]` contains the width of the widest border of the length-p prefix (with `table[0] = -1`), then `table[p+1]` is one of `1+table[p]`, `1+table[table[p]]`, ..., `1+table[table[...[table[p]]]] = 1 + table[0] = 0`.